# Unrecognized 2TB Slim External Hard Drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have been using this hard drive as a backup drive for my Ubuntu machine.

```
lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I stupidly connected this drive to my Windows machine
Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 20H2
OS build 19042.1466

I saved some data on the drive. Did a safe eject.

Plugged it in to my Linux machine.

Now the drive fails to mount and simply beeps indefinitely.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What file system are you using on the drive? Were all of your files on the drive when you opened it on Windows? And are they still?

Comment: Does it connect via USB? Open a terminal and type `lsusb` and edit your question above with the result. Also, try powering off then connecting the drive, then powering on.

Comment: If Windows fast start up is on, then it set hibernation flag. You now can only manually mount read only. Go back to Windows turn fast start up off & safely unmount. But you should not be using NTFS for any Linux backup as ownership & permissions are lost. You many be able to reset on data only files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I plugged in the drive again last night. And the behavior stopped. I can see all the files and all the data. I did run these two commands. 

df and ls /dev

I am not certain why this works now. I had changed nothing what so ever. It is just that time had simply passed.

Comment: and I had both of these listed..  /dev/sda1 
/dev/sdb1

Comment: BTW the most current version is 20.04.3 You might consider doing an update-upgrade